# Heroku: Compiled Slug Size is too large yet my file sizes are small

Tags: heroku, tweets

I am trying to deploy my tweetbot to Heroku but thins have refused to be pushed because of this error below;

```
Compressing...
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 617.8M is too large (max is 500M).
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 1a2970cd3545cb60eb76f77769d6cf7c58d3c4ae     
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 1a2970cd3545cb60eb76f77769d6cf7c58d3c4ae
remote:  ! at least twice.
```

My files are very small so I don't know where the 617M size is coming from

What is the way forward? Thank you.

Comment: Could be any number of things. What dependencies does your app declare?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to try and help. Let me ask another question with all the relevant information needed.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to add the relevant information instead of asking another one.